# Way of executing a selected block of markdown in rstudio (with knitr)

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

Is there a way to test-out and peek at the output of a selected portion of markdown in RStudio? It seems you either run R code or have to compile the entire RMD page in order to see the output.

Comment: Why don't you add `eval=FALSE` to unwanted chunks and compile entire Rmd with only wanted ("selected") chunks?

Comment: The question is about markdown chunks, which exist out of the chunks. For example, `There are \`r nrow(my_data)\` individuals.` How do you select something like that, and see it compiled as rmarkdown

Answer (score 1):

This is a Windows-only solution and it uses the clipboard instead of the current selection:

Define the following function:

```
preview <- function() {
  output <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
  input <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rmd")
  writeLines(text = readClipboard(), con = input)
  rmarkdown::render(input = input, output_file = output)
  rstudioapi::viewer(output)
}
```

Then, copy the markdown you want to preview and run `preview()`. Note that the output might be different from the output in the final document because

- the code is evaluated in the current environment
- only the copied markdown is evaluated, meaning that the snippet has no context whatsoever.

---

A solution without using the clipboard will most likely employ `rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()`. It boils down to something along the lines of a modified `preview` function

```
preview2 <- function() {
  code <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$selection
  # drop first line
  # compile document (as in preview())
  # stop execution (THIS is the problem)
}
```

which could be used by running `preview()` followed by the markdown to render:

```
preview2()
The value of pi is `r pi`.
```

The problem is, I don't see how the execution could be halted after calling `preview2()` to prevent R from trying to parse `The value of …`. See [this related discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-completely-stop-a-script-after-stop-td3218808.html).

Comment: Nice try, but your caveats (code only in current environment and no variables from preceding sections) mean that this is inpractical--it does not solve the real-world problem that I (and I suspect OP) have.

Comment: @Tripartio Yes ... but somehow, this whole question (and answer) is outdated since the introduction of the Notebook mode: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/notebook.html

Comment: CL, as far as I can tell, notebook mode (which I use extensively) only works for main R chunks, not for inline chunks embedded in the markdown text. Unless you can correct me (for which I would be thrilled!), notebook mode does not help with that problem. That is what I understand to be OP's problem, and is still my unsolved problem.

Comment: @Tripartio I'm afraid I cannot correct you. Sorry, I just skimmed the question before writing my comment and did not notice that this was about inline code.